# I'd like to merge data sets using an SQL query from different servers (one Sybase the other MS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

Is that possible?  I'm using Aquadesk and I can't get it to work.  The tables have a matching unique identifier and wondering if I can match them up in some way.

Comment: On your sql server, set up a linked server to Sybase.

Comment: That sounds like a non query option?  I only do queries and write code to do stuff locally with the data.  I don't have control over the servers.  I can ask our admins though if they have a way if that's the only option I have.

Comment: I don't know what Aquadesk is.  I assume it's some sort of programming language.  What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: Sorry I meant Aquadata

http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html

Which allows me to connect to servers and run queries.

The only thing I've tried is some syntax I've found online...

[server].[db].[table] tab1

but that didn't seem to work and I wasn't sure what "tab1" represented.  I can ask our dbas so it isn't a big deal but I asked them a bunch of questions already so was hoping to not keep annoying :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need - as I think - are "Federated Servers" (Databases)   (you can look this up)

The basic idea behind that is, the you can create (catalog) a table in you local Database that is already residing on an other Database (or Server, or even an other DB System, but that depends in you SQL system and version) -> *that is defintely a question for your DBAS*

You get a table like 'MYSQL'.'PERSONS' that resides remotely (eg. 'BASE','PERSDATA'), so you can use them in a

```
`SELECT * 
   from 'LOCALNAME'.'USERS usr 
   JOIN 'MYSQL'.'PERSONS' pers 
      on usr.user_id=pers.id`
```

So jou can select and join over different Databases (and Servers)

I only used that whith IBM/UDB but it works realy fine, and has a fair performance (altough heavily depending on your statement)